# 404 Not Found when using istio virtual service and appgateway

Tags: kubernetes-helm, istio, istio-gateway

I'm working on an app and using istio virtual service and gateway for URL but getting 404 error. Below is my Virtual services and appgateway file.

```
# Source: superset/templates/app_gateway.yaml

apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1beta1

kind: Gateway

metadata:

  name: superset

  namespace: superset

  labels:

    app: superset
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway
  servers:
    
    - port:
        number: 443
        name: https
        protocol: HTTP
      hosts:
        - "*.ap-southeast-1.elb.amazonaws.com"
        - "superset.dev"
---
# Source: superset/templates/virtualservice.yaml
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: superset
  namespace: superset
  labels:
    app: superset
spec:
  hosts:
    - "*.ap-southeast-1.elb.amazonaws.com"
    - "superset.dev"
  gateways:
  - superset
  http:
  - name: superset
    match:
    - uri:
        prefix: /superset/
    rewrite:
      uri: /
    route:
    - destination:
        host: superset.superset.svc.cluster.local
```

and tls is in values.yaml

```
tls: 
    httpsRedirect: true
```

I'm getting 404 error when trying to hit the url "superset.dev". also when checking the logs got below

```
"route_not_found"

"response_code":404,"bytes_sent"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here the prefix you have configured is "/superset/", So you need to add the prefix along with the host.

```
superset.dev/superset
```